# ORDER BY no me funciona en php?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mvc, select, model-view-controller

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con MVC (modelo-vista-controlador) y mi intención es que en la vista me salgan los alimentos que tengo en la BD (conseguido) y que el usuario pueda escoger si quiere ordenar esos alimentos por nombre, energia o grasa en orden ascendente o descendente.

Este es el código de mi vista:

```
public function listarOrdenados() 
    {
        $params = array('alimentos' => array());
        
        $m = new    Model(Config::$mvc_bd_hostname,Config::$mvc_bd_usuario,Config::$mvc_bd_clave,Config::$mvc_bd_nombre);
        
        $params['alimentos'] = $m->dameAlimentos();
        
        $tipoOrden = "";
        $sentidoOrden ="";


        if (isset($_POST['btn_ordenar'])) {
            $tipoOrden = ($_POST['tipo_orden']);
            $sentidoOrden = ($_POST['sentido_orden']);
        }       
        if ($tipoOrden === 'orden_nombre' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoNombre_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_nombre' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoNombre_desc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_energia' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoEnergia_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_energia' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoEnergia_desc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_grasa' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoGrasa_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_grasa' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoGrasa_desc();
        } 

        require 'templates/mostrarAlimentos_orden.php'; //vista de este apartado
  
    }
```

Esta la función que estoy utilizando en el controlador:

```
public function listarOrdenados() 
    {
        $params = array('alimentos' => array());
        
        $m = new Model(Config::$mvc_bd_hostname,Config::$mvc_bd_usuario,Config::$mvc_bd_clave,Config::$mvc_bd_nombre);
        
        $params['alimentos'] = $m->dameAlimentos();
        
        $tipoOrden = "";
        $sentidoOrden ="";


        if (isset($_POST['btn_ordenar'])) {
            $tipoOrden = ($_POST['tipo_orden']);
            $sentidoOrden = ($_POST['sentido_orden']);
        }       
        if ($tipoOrden === 'orden_nombre' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoNombre_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_nombre' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoNombre_desc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_energia' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoEnergia_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_energia' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoEnergia_desc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_grasa' && $sentidoOrden === 'ascendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoGrasa_asc();
        }
        elseif ($tipoOrden === 'orden_grasa' && $sentidoOrden === 'descendente') {
            $params['alimentos'] = $m->ordenarAlimentoGrasa_desc();
        } 

        require 'templates/mostrarAlimentos_orden.php'; //vista de este apartado
  
    } 
}
```

Las funciones del Modelo:

```
    public function dameAlimentos() 
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos"; 
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql); 
    }
```

```
private function devolverAlimentosSelect($sql) 
    {
        $consulta = $this->conexion->query($sql); 
        $alimentos = array(); 
        while($resultado = $consulta->fetch_array()) 
        { 
            $alimentos[] = $resultado; 
        } 
        return $alimentos; 
    }
```

```
public function ordenarAlimentoNombre_asc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY nombre ASC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
    public function ordenarAlimentoNombre_desc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY nombre DESC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
    public function ordenarAlimentoEnergia_asc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY energia ASC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
    
    public function ordenarAlimentoEnergia_desc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY energia DESC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
    
    public function ordenarAlimentoGrasa_asc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY grasa ASC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
    
    public function ordenarAlimentoGrasa_desc(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos ORDER BY grasa DESC";
        return $this->devolverAlimentosSelect($sql);
    }
```

Código de la vista:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>

<h2>Ver alimentos</h2>
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th>alimento (por 100g)</th> 
        <th>energia (Kcal)</th> 
        <th>grasa (g)</th> 
    </tr> 
    <?php foreach ($params['alimentos'] as 
 $alimento) :?> 
    <tr> 
        <td><a href="index.php?ruta=ver&id=<?php 
 echo $alimento['id']?>"><?php echo 
 $alimento['nombre'] ?></a></td> 
        <td><?php echo $alimento['energia']?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $alimento['grasatotal']?> 
</td> 
    </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
<form method="post" action="index.php? 
ruta=listar_ordenados">

<p>Ordenar por <select name="tipo_orden">

<option value="orden_nombre">nombre</option>

<option value="orden_energia">energia</option>

<option value="orden_grasa">grasa</option>

</select> en sentido <select name="sentido_orden">
<option value="ascendente">ascendente</option>
<option value="descendente">descendente</option>
</select></p>
<input type="submit" value="Ordenar" 
id="btn_ordenar">
</form>

<?php $contenido = ob_get_clean() ?>

<?php include 'layout.php' ?>
```

Cuando en la vista le doy al botón de "Ordenar" además de no ordenarse los campos en la tabla cuando escojo cualquier opción se recarga la página y me vuelve a mostrar por defecto la option "nombre" y "ascendente".

Comment: Muestra el HTML del form. Por otro lado te recomendaría preguntar como mejorar el código que tienes, porque si tuvieras una tabla con 50 columnas para ordenar te vuelves loco creando 50 `if` y 50 funciones para los ascendentes y otras 50+50 para los descendientes

Comment: @Yussef cierto, se me olvidó mostrar el HTML del form, lo acabo de añadir a la pregunta, gracias por la observación, sí que es cierto lo de crear tantos ifs, lo único que primero estoy buscando que me funcione y luego ya buscaré como "limpiar" el código para que quede lo más simple, reducido y legible posible. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto era lo que he modificado y con lo que he conseguido arreglarlo:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['tipo_orden'])) {
        $tipoOrden = ($_REQUEST['tipo_orden']);
        $sentidoOrden = ($_REQUEST['sentido_orden']);
    }
```